# Formula to match perceived font color to a desired RGB value

Tags: html, css, fonts, colors

Have you noticed that anti-aliased fonts look different than the RGB value you prescribe? On a white background fonts look lighter, on dark backgrounds they look darker, and on colored backgrounds they can take on completely different hue.

I usually adjust font colors by eyeing differences in the browser and changing rgb values until I'm satisfied that the font appears to adhere to the overall palette.

For example, on the Google home page the "G" in Google is roughly #1C70FF, it appears to be roughly the same color as the search button which is a gradient #4387fd,#4683ea. These are two different colors but they are perceived to be very similar.

[image]

Im not looking for perfection, I'm just trying to push fonts closer to a perceived match. Is there a calculation that would help achieve this goal?

Comment: Sadly not, because font-rendering is a browser-specific thing. Results in one browser will look different in another. Additionally, perceived colour may vary with the screen. If I change the brightness of my phone's backlight, perceived colours change.

Comment: True. There are many factors, the level of font smoothing for example is one major factor. At the end of the day, you're probably spot on, but I asked the question because I believe in the ingenuity and expertise of the community. Thanks for your comment.